# A ordem dos Parâmetros em JS importa?

Tags: javascript

Estava fazendo um função para criar um colisão quando percebi que, a função agia de formas diferentes dependendo da ordem dos parâmetros, no que está funcionando a colisão ocorre quando o FLappybird é maior ou igual a altura do chão

Quando mudei a ordem dos parâmetros a função de colisão era chama assim que eu abria o navegador

Funcionando:

```
function Colide(Flappybird,chao){
const FY=Flappybird.y+Flappybird.altura
const CY= chao.y
if(FY>=CY){
   return true
}
   return false
}
```

Não funcionando:

```
function Colide(chao,Flappybird){
const FY=Flappybird.y+Flappybird.altura
const CY= chao.y
if(FY>=CY){
   return true
}
   return false
}
```

Comment: Para a função em si não importa a ordem, mas importa para quem chamar a função, que precisa passar os parâmetros na ordem correta

Comment: O nome da assinatura da função nao faz diferença, ocorrerá diferença se no if tiver considerando um padrão de ordem ou na chamada da mesma.. caso não tiver usando parâmetros fixo, como  padrão

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, tá dando erro porquê você tá manualmente trocando os parâmetros de lugar na função `Colide`.

Quando você muda elas (os parâmetros) de lugar desse jeito que você fez e chama a função igual antes, os valores que serão usados dentro da função serão diferentes.

Por exemplo:

```
function retornaMeuNome(nome, sobrenome) {
    return nome + " " + sobrenome;
}
```

Quando você chama a função acima assim

```
retornaMeuNome('Vinicius', 'Gouveia');
```

o retorno será

```
// "Vinicius Gouveia"
```

Mas se você troca a ordem dos parâmetros diretamente na função

```
function retornaMeuNome(sobrenome, nome) { // Troca de lugar os parâmetros
    return nome + " " + sobrenome;
}
```

o retorno será

```
// "Gouveia Vinicius"
```

Para funcionar, você precisaria alterar a forma de como sua função trabalha, por exemplo, trocando o retorno para

```
return sobrenome + " " + nome;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
// parametro 1
var param1 = (p1,p2)  =>{
     if(p1 > p2){
        console.log("P1 maior "+p1);
     }else if (p2 >= p1){
        console.log("P2 testado "+p2);
     }
      
}

// parametro 2
var param2 = function(){
       console.log(arguments.length+" - argumentos passados ");
       
       console.log("acessando :  "+arguments[0]+ "  "+ arguments[3]);
      
       
}

// parametro 3
function param3(p1="Js",p2=13){
    console.log("é um "+ typeof p1);
    console.log("é um "+ typeof p2);
}


param1(5,3);
param2(1,2,5,13);
param3("ld");
```

Na primeira função; havera diferença no resultado caso mude a ordem dos valores, pois existe  uma verificação que depende de 2 argumentos a serem passados, na chamada da função obriga a passar 2 valores para apresentar o resultado.

Ja na função 2, não passar nenhum argumento sera mostrado "undefined" mas não  foi definido uma quantidade a ser passada pode ser 1 ou 100 argumentos que sera acessado por índices... a quantidade importa e o resultado depende da posição, se desejar acessar um dado valor.

A função 3, não importa os valores,  ja ta definido um padrão que sera subscrito caso passe outro parâmetro desde que seja 2, segui a ideia da primeira função.
havera diferença se no primeiro parâmetro deseja um literal mas passar um número ou o resultado depende do primeiro valor.